# F# How to split an integer into a new list where each element is a position of the integer

Tags: f#

I am trying to convert an integer into a list. For example I have the number 561, it would be converted into a list composed of: [5; 6; 1]. How would I do this?
Currently I have:

```
let rec convertInt x = 
[]
```

I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this solution. The code should be self-explanatory, please leave a comment if something is unclear.

```fs
let rec convertInt x =
    if x < 10 then
        [ x ]
    else
        convertInt (x / 10) @ [ x % 10 ]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how to complete the function as I am fairly new to F#. Your solution really helped me understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
let convertInt (x: int) =
    x.ToString()
    |> Seq.map (fun char -> int char - int '0')
    |> List.ofSeq
```